# Extjs: Passing variable in store to controller

Tags: javascript, extjs, datastore

I have a custom View object that is rendered from a datastore in Extjs:

```
Ext.define('MemOS.view.Shortcut', {
    extend: 'Ext.view.View',
    alias: 'widget.shortcut',

    name: 'shortcut',
    singleSelect: true,
    store: 'Apps',
    tpl: [
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '<div id="iconGroup" class="icon-wrap">',
                '<div id="icon" class="icon">',
                    '<img src="/images/icons/" />',
                '</div>',
                '<span> {appName} </span>',
            '</div>',
        '</tpl>'
    ],  
    itemSelector: 'div.icon',
    plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.ux.DataView.DragSelector', {}),
        //Ext.create('Ext.ux.DataView.Draggable', {})
    ],
});
```

I also have a controller with an event that is called when an item in the store is double clicked:

```
Ext.define('MemOS.controller.Shortcut', {
    extend: ('Ext.app.Controller'),
    stores: ['Apps'],
    views: ['Shortcut'],

    ref: [{
            ref: 'shortcut-one',
            selection: '',
            xtype: 'shortcut',
            autoCreate: true        
    }],

    init: function(){
        this.control({
            'shortcut': {
                itemdblclick: function(d, i, n, e) {
                    console.log('Display Value From Data Store Here');
                }
            }
        });
    },
});
```

What I would like to do is pass the datastore value of the item that is clicked through to the controller, so that I can then display the appropriate value in an alert box. My goal is to later use this to open a specific window/app based on the users click.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Again, the information is in the docs:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.view.View-event-itemdblclick

The second parameter passed is the record, so you can access any of the values in the record using record.get()

```
itemdblclick: function(view, record) {
    console.log(record.get('nameOfField'));
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm relatively new to programming and trying to muddle my way through this. I've read the docs, but don't see how I can access the specific field or value I need.

Comment: Updated with a code sample. If you're new to programming, you're going to have a really tough time.

Comment: Thanks. Why do you think I'll have a tough time?